# Inflation in new aeons (cyclic cosmology)

Tags: spacetime, cosmological-inflation, scale-invariance

I have a question pertaining to Penrose's ideas about cyclic cosmology. As predicted therein, the end of each cycle comes about when massive particles are extinct and time is no longer measured. What I don't understand is why this state is not an eternal one; what could possibly give rise to a new period of inflation, is it that energy is somehow bound in time as a dimension?